# React Native - display promised images in flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

I currently have multiple categories, and each of them have an array that contains the names of images. These arrays are fetched from a JSON file, I hope to use a flatList to display them. However when I do the following attempt, it says **cannot read property '0' of undefined**...

```
export default function display() {

const [all, setAll] = useState([])

const fetching = async() => {

     ... //code that fetches the JSON file

     setImages([{title: "A", arr: arrA},
                    {title: "B", arr: arrB},
                    {title: "C", arr: arrC}]
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetching();
}, [])

...

    const display = ({arr}) => ... //function that displays the pictures
 

    const Item = ({title, arr}) => {
        return(
        <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
            
            {display(arr)}
            <Text style={styles.tags}>{title}</Text>

        </View>
        )
    }

    const renderItem = (item) => {
        return(
            <Item title={item.title}
                arr={item.arr}/>
        ) 
    }

    return (
        <View> 
            {console.log(all)}
            <FlatList
             data={all}
             renderItem={renderItem}
             keyExtractor={item => item.title}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

The console.log in the return statement shows this:
[console.log(all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fcpA.png)

Which part of my code is wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: add a loader and wait for the images to be fetched.

Comment: @JuniusL. could you please specify where should I add the loader? is it to create a isLoading state and put it inside useEffect? Sorry I'm quite new to React Native :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loader set it true when fetching the images and false after the call to fetch the images has done.

```
const [all, setAll] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setLoader] = useState(true);

const fetching = async() => {

 ... //code that fetches the JSON file
 setLoader(false);
 setImages([{title: "A", arr: arrA},
                {title: "B", arr: arrB},
                {title: "C", arr: arrC}]
 }
```

Then in your render check if the loader is false or not

```
return (
    <View> 
        { isLoading 
         ? <Text>Loading...</Text> 

         : <FlatList
            data={all}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.title}/>
         }
    </View>
)
```